# `Format profile` property in MediaInfo

Tags: file-formats, capturing

I got two media files: the first is an application window capture, the second is desktop cature. The only difference between them is that one has `format profile` section with value `OpenDML` in `MediaInfo`, and the other hasn't. All other information are the same (besides only file specific: *size*, *duration* and *bit rate*).

What does the `format profile` field mean? The files are produced by one media program with the same output settings. How it may affect media file?

**UPDATE**

I'm just interesting how the encoding software chooses what to put into this field. Is that field just a text info provided by encoder on its own (like description, notes, etc) or it is some kind of property for decoding software to take appropriate actions?

Answer (score 1):

OpenDML is just a slight difference in the internal arrangement of an AVI file allowing it to go beyond the 2GB limit and supports a few other new features.  It shouldn't have any particular impact on the data within the file, though I'm unsure why one file was stored that way and the other was not.  Perhaps the software you were using only includes the extra format data if going beyond 2GB.

Comment: By the way, the files are less than gigabyte.

Comment: @rook - hmm, no idea why the difference then.